# I Can't Get Xdebug To Be Installed On My Mac?

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

i have tried to install xdebug on my mac using home-brew everything seems alright, with no errors, but when i execute phpinfo method i don't find debug module there, i have tried million times with no success, so i have read an answer here in StackOverFlow for the same reason which suggests follow these instructions http://xdebug.org/wizard.php i have copied all code source of phpinfo page, and they gave me detailed instructions, i have followed there guide with no errors after restarting my server and refresh phpinfo page, and still no xdebug !!

php.ini - http://pastebin.com/RLyzXJ9z 
phpinfo() code source -  http://pastebin.com/H8XVX5GG

Comment: If you type `php -m` on the command line, do you see  Xdebug in the list of modules?

Comment: Yes, i have just tried it and it shows xdebug !! two debug, one with [Zend Modules] and other without !!

Comment: I can't read your phpinfo() paste.  what is the path of the php.ini file that's loaded as your config

Comment: Also, are you using php-fpm or mod_php in apache?

Comment: Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php.ini, how do i know which one ? because i have just followed a tutorial !!

Comment: Restart your apache (or php-fpm if running nginx) and look in you php error log to see if you get a warning about the module being incorrect for the version of php you're using.

Comment: thats the error i found about xdebug: [Mon Jul 07 20:52:25 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
Cannot load Xdebug - it was built with configuration API220100525,NTS,debug, whereas running engine is API220100525,NTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, the version of Xdebug isn't the one that matches the version of php running in either your Apache mod_php or your php-fpm (if you're on nginx).

I'm guessing if you used `brew`, your CLI php is really in `/usr/local/something...` and that matches the version for your xdebug.  On the other hand you whatever PHP flavor you're using for your webserver to work with is different.

My vote would be to ditch the local php or brew installed version and use something like MAMP that runs 100% it's own libraries.  Adding Xdebug to MAMP is pretty well documented if you google for it.